# Need BLUETOOTH permission : i don't have permission in some intent Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an app with a MainActivity that opens other activities. When I use bluetooth for activities other than the Main, it gives me this kind of error.
While in my MainActivity this is not a problem.

It tells me that I don't have the permissions :

```
2022-01-07 18:50:38.881 9466-9466/com.example.myapplication_dynahers E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication_dynahers, PID: 9466
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication_dynahers/com.example.myapplication_dynahers.Calibration_Activity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH permission: Neither user 10446 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH permission: Neither user 10446 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH.
```

while my Manifest.xml specifies the permissions:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication_dynahers">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BlUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication_DynaHERS">
        <activity
            android:name=".Active_Bluetooth_Activity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Reset_Force_Activity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Calibration_Activity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Graph_Activity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Using_Version_Activity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Modify_Interval_Activity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Where could the problem come from?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my error: I actually put the correct permissions in the Manifest (I may be missing the permission for the location because it is possible to locate a device with bluetooth), but what I forgot to do is check the permissions in the code. This should solve my problem.